# AutoName resolution with Jaxb

Tags: jaxb, cxf

Apache CXF supports automatic name resolution when finding duplicated bindings in WSDL / XSD through the autoNameResolution argument but there doesn't seem to be an equivalent for XJC.

Is it possible to auto-resolve name problems with XJC or to use Apache CXF just to compile XSD schemas?